# What's This Holiday Rebus?

Tags: rebus, seasonal

What is the meaning of this rebus? Just in time for the holidays! A good message to share.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The good message is

> [Love the giver more than the gift.](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/brigham_young_146731)